# Create and add a User to group in Django for tests purpose

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I need to test a simple Django project where users in a certain group have some permissions. Now in tests I know how to create a mock user and I have already tested that users not in the group can't access the data trow API, but now I have to test that users in group can access to data. How I can create and add the mock user the group?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Below my code:

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.urls import reverse
from mixer.backend.django import mixer
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, HTTP_200_OK
from rest_framework.test import APIClient


@pytest.fixture()
def superheroes(db):
    return [
        mixer.blend('superhero.SuperHero')
    ]


def get_client(user=None):
    res = APIClient()
    if user is not None:
        res.force_login(user)
    return res

# code to test users without permissions (it works!)
def test_anon_user_forbidden():
    path = reverse('superheroes-list')
    client = get_client()
    response = client.get(path)
    assert response.status_code == HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN

# code to test users with permission (so users that are in the group)
def test_avengers_user_ok(superheroes):
    path = reverse('superheroes-list')
    user = mixer.blend(get_user_model())
    # add the user to specific group, but how?
    client = get_client(user)
    response = client.get(path)
    assert response.status_code == HTTP_200_OK
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization `myuser.groups.add(group, group, ...)`

Comment: @Anentropic yes I have already tried with `user.groups.add(Group(name='Avengers'))` but it doesn't work, I get the error `ValueError: Cannot add "<Group: Avengers>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None"`

Comment: ah, there is your real problem then.  do you have pytest-django plugin? it's weird the  Group seems to be on database "None"... this is a db name from `DATABASES` settings config

Comment: I resolve the issues with `group = mixer.blend(Group, name='Avengers')
    user.groups.add(group)`, thx for your answers!